# Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: flutter

I am using Linux. When try to run the following in Terminal:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

It's showing me the following error:

> flutter: command not found

Comment: Is this even a problem for you, i.e. does this hinder you to build applications?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I'd assume `flutter: command not found` is hindering ;-)

Comment: Where do you get "Some Android licenses not accepted" when `flutter` can't be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run command `whereis flutter`. If that does not give you path/output then you have not set flutter path correctly.

Add the below line in your ~/.bash_profile file:

`export PATH=<this is where you have to put your flutter path >/flutter/bin:$PATH`
`source ~/.bash_profile`

now `whereis flutter`should give you the correct path and you wont get
`flutter: command not found`

Comment: Your app code is not working or flutter command is not working? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and accept all licenses by entering `y`
 for all the licenses. After that Retype

```
flutter doctor
```

You are now Good to go.

Comment: The question says that the flutter command is not found. This answer does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I am use IntelIdea and have same problem like another guys.<>, but this command not working if use paste copy, after few hours when i try find the right way to resolve this problem, push, on IntelIdea Tools->Flutter->Flutter Doctor and i see on command line <>. So i copy this row to terminal delete --verbose and write --android-licenses PRESS ENTER. ... O miracle i see the right  result "All SDK package licenses accepted"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?